# evaluate string as code VBA

Tags: vba, replace, eval, ms-word, execute

I have a subroutine with optional parameters

```
Public Sub FaR_Wild_Stories_Extras(ByVal rngStory As Word.Range, _
    ByVal strSearch As String, ByVal strReplace As String, _
    Optional extra1 As String = "", Optional extra2 As String = "")
  With rngStory.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = strSearch
    .Replacement.Text = strReplace
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .IgnorePunct = True
    .IgnoreSpace = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    If extra1 <> "" Then eval(extra1)
    If extra2 <> "" Then eval(extra2)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

I want to be able to place something like "`.font.size=14`" or `.MatchDiacritics = False` for example in `extra1` and evaluate it, so that, when invoking a find and replace subroutine if there are specific extra params I want to include in the find and replace as a one time thing, I don't have to create a whole separate sub for it.

Is there a way to do this?  Eval() doesn't seem to exist in word VBA.
Object.string isn't possible, is there some smarter way I could structure my code other than duplicating the subroutine or having a subroutine with 10s of rarely used, optional arguments?

For a more generalised case, is it possible to `call` a sub like this, or structure code by passing arguments cleverly to have the same effect

```
...
call Example , true, ".prop1=5", ".prop2=6"
...

Sub Example1(x, Optional param1 As String, Optional param2 As String)
    With Application.ExampleObject
        .property1 = "foo"
        .property2 = x
        Expand (param1)
        Expand (param2)
        .excecute
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe it should be `Evaluate()`, but I'm completely uncertain whether or not this would work

Comment: evaluate() is an excel specific function that works on worksheet formulae rather than vba code (e.g. `evaluate("sum(a1:d4))"`    )

Comment: Even in excel eval/Evaluateis just a mechanism to invoke a function. What you are trying to to do in your example is Set properties to an object. As far as I know, VBA doesn't  supports such feature. To tweak a property you will first need an instance of the object and then reflect it to replace/ add the property values. .Net / Java support reflection, VBA doesn't.

Comment: So what do you recommend I do?  I could create a new sub for each combination of properties I end up using (involves a lot of code duplication)?  I could create a behemoth of a sub with a bunch of optional arguments for every property I might care to use in the future (better, but still ugly)   Or is there a smarter way that achieves a similar purpose, that is to say invoke a subroutine which includes a method within it defined by multiple parameters, without specifying all of these potentially used parameters in the arguments of the subroutine?

Comment: @cyboashu turns out this is in fact possible, see my answer below.

Comment: yeah, you totally nailed it. who cares for reflection. :) Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Best option

CallByName allows you to set a Property or invoke a Method with an Object named by a string.

```
Sub Example(x, Optional Method1 As String ="", _
            Optional Param1 As String = "", Optional Param1Value as Variant)

    Dim MyObject as Object 
    Set MyObject = Application.ExampleObject

    'invoke a method from its name
    if method1 <> "" Then CallByName MyObject, Method1, VbMethod
    'set a property from its name and a variant representing the value to set
    if param1 <> "" Then CallByName MyObject, Param1, VbSet, Param1Value

    With MyObject
        .property1 = "foo"
        .property2 = x       
        .excecute
    End With
End Sub
```

(For info on how to handle properties with more than one value elegantly, see this thread http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?405366-RESOLVED-Using-CallByName-with-variable-number-of-arguments)

#### Earlier solution

Farm out rarely-used properties to external subroutine. Still could be useful in combination with the above if you don't want to clutter up the arguments of your Main Subroutine.

```
Sub Example(x, Optional ExternalSub as String)
    'pull any additional rarely used properties from another sub
    Application.Run(ExternalSub)

    With Application.ExampleObject
        .property1 = "foo"
        .property2 = x       
        .excecute
    
End Sub

Sub External_MoreProperties
    Application.ExampleObject.property3 = "bar"
End Sub
```

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps "It's not possible to evaluate a string as code in vba" should read "There is no straight-forward way to evaluate a string as code in vba". VBA is Turing complete. You could write your own parser if worse comes to worse. Also -- the VBA editor is scriptable, and you can use it to dynamically generate code. But, there is nothing which is as immediately usable as e.g. Python's `exec()` function.

Comment: @JohnColeman Exactly! And [write our own parser, compiler and evaluator we did!](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/stdLambda.cls) :D

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but in this case I would use [`stdLambda`](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/stdLambda.cls).

stdLambda is an external library, developed (mostly by myself) to bring a full parser, compiler and evaluator to VBA. We parse VBA-like code, convert it into byte code, and then evaluate it when needed, all within the VBA runtime!

Usage should be very straight forward for this use case:

```
Public Sub FaR_Wild_Stories_Extras(ByVal rngStory As Word.Range, _
ByVal strSearch As String, ByVal strReplace As String, _
Optional ByVal extraFilters As stdICallable)

    Dim f as Find
    set f = rngStory.Find
    With f
       'Default search params:
       .ClearFormatting
       .Replacement.ClearFormatting
       .Text = strSearch
       .Replacement.Text = strReplace
       .Forward = True
       .MatchWildcards = True
       .MatchCase = True
       .IgnorePunct = True
       .IgnoreSpace = True
       .Format = False
       .Wrap = wdFindContinue
       Call extraFilters.Run(f)
       .Execute Replace:= wdReplaceAll
    End With
 End Sub
 Sub Main()
    Call FaR_Wild_Stories_Extras(Doc.Contents, "Hello","Bye", stdLambda.CreateMultiline( _ 
        "$1.Font.Size = 10", _ 
        "$1.MatchDiacritics = False" _ 
    ))
 End Sub
```